# Subset repeated elements based on a list

Tags: sas

is there a way to subset from a data set some IDs based on an external list?
In other words, I have a data set:

> ```
>  ID        Value   
> 0001        0.3
> 0001        0.6
> 0002        0.7
> 0002        0.71
> 0002        0.43
> 0003        0.01
> 0003        0.2
> 0005        12
> 0005        11
> ```

and a list:

> ```
>  ID         
> 0001    
> 0002        
> 0005
> ```

The desired output would be:

> ```
>  ID        Value   
> 0001        0.3
> 0001        0.6
> 0002        0.7
> 0002        0.71
> 0002        0.43
> 0005        12
> 0005        11
> ```

My point is that in the data set, IDs are repeated.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why is ID = 0003 not in the final data? It is in the external list?

Comment: Sorry, just edited. I made a mistake while writing.

Comment: how do you get the list of your IDs that you want to keep, is it an external file or a fixed list or should a user have a choice which IDs to keep?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing it is by saving your IDs from external list into macro variable, and then use select statement using that variable.

```
data have;
    input ID Value;
    format ID z4.;
    datalines;
0001 0.3
0001 0.6
0002 0.7
0002 0.71
0002 0.43
0003 0.01
0003 0.2
0005 12
0005 11
;
run;
```

This list can be imported from an external file using proc import (in this example I used external xlsx file, located at &path.).

```
proc import 
    datafile="&path."
    out=list
    dbms=xlsx
    replace;
run;
```

Or can be a separate existing table.

```
data list;
    input ID;
    datalines;
0001
0002
0005
;
run;
```

Here we save IDs from your list into a macro variable x.

```
proc sql noprint;
    select ID into :x separated by ','
        from list
    ;
quit;
```

When you have your selected IDs in a macro variable you can use that for a simple select statement.

```
proc sql;
    create table want as
        select *
            from have
                where ID in (&x.)
    ;
quit;
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL is the easiest for sure. Assuming ID list is in a data set, you can do something like this:

HAVE: Input data set with all records
ID_LIST: input data set with ids to be selected

```
proc sql;
create table want as
select * from have
where ID in 
          (select id from id_list);
quit;
```

There are several other ways to solve this including a data step merge (requires pre-sorting) and/or a hash table.